when using Ocelot, the ContentLength is 0 when forwarding data to downstream services
Using Ocelot version 18.0, in an ABP framework environment, the content length of front-end access is normal when using app.Use. However, when inspecting the information forwarded by Ocelot in a DelegatingHandler, the content length is 0.
Thanks
